Type Error: Unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'NoneType' (Python 3.10.12)
I'm encountering a type error in my Python code using union types. Here's the relevant snippet:
import sys

print(sys.version)


class Node:
  def __init__(self, data: str, parent: "Node" | None = None):
    self.data = data
    self.parent = parent
    self.child = []

class Tree:
  def __init__(self, data: str):
    self.root = Node(data)

  def insert_child(self, data: str, parent: Node | None = None):
    if not parent:
        self.root.child.append(Node(data, self.root))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  root_dir = Tree("root")

Error Message:
3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tree.py", line 13, in <module>
    class Node:
  File "tree.py", line 14, in Node
    def __init__(self, data: str, parent: "Node" | None = None):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'NoneType'

Despite using Python 3.10 and the correct syntax for union types, I'm getting this error. What could be causing this issue? Are there any additional checks I should perform?
